# How to set MongoMemoryReplSet port

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, jestjs, mongo-memory-server

I'm trying to start a MongoMemoryReplSet instance for testing against with jest.  However, when I set the configuration to a specific port, it is ignored and a random port assigned.  Can anyone see what is wrong with my configuration as I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
const mongoServer = await MongoMemoryReplSet.create({ 
        instanceOpts:[
            {
              port: 55555,// port number I want to set for the instance
            }
        ],
        replSet: { 
            dbName: 'myDatabase',
            auth: false,
            count: 1 
        } 
    });

console.log({mongoServerGetUri: mongoServer.getUri()})

// output 
//  { mongoServerGetUri: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:63956/?replicaSet=testset' }
```

Thanks